# Как мне скомпилировать код из String в файл .class() и поместить его в jar?

Tags: java

Мне нужно написать класс, который будет компилировать сорцы класса и помещать их в jar. Как в jar поместить .class, примерно представляю. Хотелось бы узнать, как можно скомпилировать строку в class файл, или может есть такое решение, которое убьёт двух зайцев одним выстрелом и засунет сорцы из строки в банку(.jar)?

Comment: Выглядит как то костыльно. Какую бизнес-задачу вы решаете?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ранее я задавался этим же вопросом.

Чтобы динамически скомпилировать класс можно воспользоваться библиотеками вроде `bytebuddy`,`cglib`,`javasist` итд. которые ***генерируют java байткод***.

Есть и более простой способ - ***компиляция исходного кода***. Для этих целей в стандартной библиотеке уже есть необходимый `api`.

Следующий метод, принимает на вход название класса и строку содержающую программный код на `java`. Далее создается директория во временном каталоге и туда сохраняется скомпилированный класс. Возвращает метод путь до этого файла.

```
private static String compile(String className, String code) throws Exception {
    JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
    StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);
    Path output = Files.createTempDirectory("_" + System.currentTimeMillis());

    JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = compiler
            .getTask(null,
                    fileManager,
                    null,
                    Arrays.asList("-d", output.toAbsolutePath().toString()),
                    null,
                    singletonList(
                            new SimpleJavaFileObject(
                                    URI.create("string:///" + className.replace('.', '/') + JavaFileObject.Kind.SOURCE.extension),
                                    JavaFileObject.Kind.SOURCE) {

                                public CharSequence getCharContent(boolean ignoreEncodingErrors) {
                                    return code;
                                }
                            })
            );

    boolean result = task.call();
    if (!result) throw new IllegalStateException("something wrong happened");

    return output.toAbsolutePath().toString();
}
```

Пример вызова:

```
String path = compile("Solution", "public class Solution{}");
```

Более подробное можете прочитать в [моей заметке](http://www.izebit.ru/2017/07/dynamic-compilation-java-code.html)

Comment: Большущее вам спасибо. Вот только вместо _singletonList_ надо писать _Collections.singletonList_

Comment: @SergeyKazantsev если сделать статический импорт то можно и без названия класса